# Copy selected contacts to other UITableView IPhone

Tags: iphone

I would like to know , how can i copy and display the selected contacts from one tableview to another tablview. I have list o contacts in a tableview. I have option of multiselect contacts. when i click on done (after selecting) i need to copy the selected contacts to another tableview. Can someone guide me how can i achieve it.

Sample example or code will be of great use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You must be having datasource for ur First tableview. so u can use
**DidSelectRowAtIndex** method, 
1) get indexpath.row and copy item from datasource at specified indexpath.row 
to a new array (which will become datasource for ur second tableview.

like below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//customArray is datasource for this tableview
NSString *item=    [self.customArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//arr is datasource for second tableview
    [arr addObject:item];
}
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
lowerLblItem_Unit_Cost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [delegate.addItem_UnitCost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    lowerLblItem_Unit_Cost.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//customArray is datasource for this tableview
NSString *item=    [self.customArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//arr is datasource for second tableview
    [arr addObject:item];

or // you can use your own label

lowerLblItem_Unit_Cost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [delegate.addItem_UnitCost objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    lowerLblItem_Unit_Cost.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 

}
```